# access to json multidimensional array with react

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I'm trying to access a certain element of my JSON, through React JS i use: `Object.keys(field)[0]` on the json and I get "punteggio" but I would like to get its value instead, for example "7". How can I access to this data?

```
  "honours": [
  {
      "punteggio" : 7,
      "serie" : "Serie A",
      "tipo" : "icon-scudetto",
      "anni" : "1926/1927 revocato, 1027/1928, 1942/1943, 1945/1946, 1947/1948"
  },
  {
      "punteggio" : 4,
      "serie" : "Serie B",
      "tipo" : "icon-scudetto",
      "anni" : "1958/1960, 1989/1990, 2000/2001, 2011/2012"
  },
  {
      "punteggio" : 5,
      "serie" : "Serie B",
      "tipo" : "icon-coppaitalia",
      "anni" : "1958/1960, 1989/1990, 2000/2001, 2011/2012"
  }
]
```

Comment: What is `field`?

Comment: `field[Object.keys(field)[0]]` (also, React is completely irrelevant to this question, and `field` is an Object, not JSON)

Answer (score 0):

"punteggio" - is just a key, so you can access its value like this

```
const key = Object.keys(field)[0];
const value = field[key];
```

Answer (score 0):

Object.Keys used when you need to fetch key of array from the object

use Object.Values to fetch the value

Read more at : 
https://javascript.info/keys-values-entries